# Google Place API in AutoCompleteTextView Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement AutocompleteTextView, but not found any solution.

I found solution of Google Place API in fragment but I need it in textview

```
public class PlaceArrayAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceArrayAdapter";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context  Context
     * @param resource Layout resource
     * @param bounds   Used to specify the search bounds
     * @param filter   Used to specify place types
     */
    public PlaceArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, LatLngBounds bounds,
                             AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, resource);
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }


    public void setGoogleApiClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
        if (googleApiClient == null || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient = null;
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is your use case?
Do you need to enter the search query in an EditText and show the results in a custom manner rather than the default one provided by Maps API ?

Comment: Yes @Ruthwik Warrier